# Does certutil's -csp "Microsoft Platform Crypto Provider" option store the private key in the TPM?

Tags: private-key, tpm, certutil

Does `certutil -csp "Microsoft Platform Crypto Provider" -importpfx` options really store the private key in the TPM?  I am wondering why the output of `certutil -key -csp "Microsoft Platform Crypto Provider"`  shows me a location on the harddisk...

> Microsoft Platform Crypto Provider:
> Test-637559044681743771-7df36675-f51c-4067-9f6d-31ca33d290b7
> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\PCPKSP\33b114867a192aae5b73a3a968437c129ab577a4\ec03c4aa087abc780c3ff6448624456b0d1bf68c.PCPKEY
> RSA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The private key is wrapped by a key in the TPM (usually the Storage Root Key) and saved to disk. The TPM has to unlock the private key, so it is still secured by the TPM.

It is possible to store a few keys in the TPM, but that's not typical.